# Most effective way to group element counter in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, counter, frequency

Suppose I have a list/tuple like that: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']`.

```
Frequency of 'a': 2
Frequency of 'b': 3
Frequency of 'c': 2
```

Now I want to group them by these frequencies, expected output: `{2: ['a', 'c'], 3: ['b']}` or anything else which I can easily to get the frequency and its items.

How can I do that in the most effective way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
>>> from collections import Counter, defaultdict
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
>>> 
>>> counts = Counter(l)
>>> freqs = defaultdict(list)
>>> 
>>> for k,v in counts.items():
...     freqs[v].append(k)
... 
>>> freqs
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {2: ['a', 'c'], 3: ['b']})
```

Comment: `for k, count in counts.items():freqs[count].append(k)` makes it clearer with slightly better naming (subjective, of course).

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. I'll notice `collections` package in Python.

Comment: @arshajii: Yes, of course. I'll but not now, because I have to wait in a few minutes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>>
>>> freq = Counter(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']).most_common()
>>> {key:[x for x, _ in grp]
...  for key, grp in groupby(freq, key=lambda tup: tup[1])}
{2: ['a', 'c'], 3: ['b']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this slightly differently.

```
from collections import defaultdict

items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
counts = defaultdict(list)
for item in set(items):
    counts[items.count(item)].append(item)
dict(counts)
```

Counts then looks like this

```
{2: set(['a', 'c']), 3: set(['b'])}
```